# ASP.NET Boilerplate: What is the best solution for Four eyes principle

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I want to add 4 eyes principle to ASP.NET Boilerplate framework. That means every change on Role, User,.. need to be approved (by another admin) before applied to the system. I have searched for some time but no answer. So what is the best solution for this flow?

Can I create the same tables with Abp tables (`dbo.AbpUser_Temp`, etc) and the all the changes will be stored in these tables? Is there any better solution?

Example: In the application, Admin1 has created a user named User1. But this user cannot login to the application until he was approved by Admin2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Simple Workflows

> Example: In the application, Admin1 has created a user named User1. But this user cannot login to the application until he was approved by Admin2.

Simple workflows like these can be appropriately handled by a property and a method:

```
public class User : AbpUser<User>
{
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

    public void Approve(User approver)
    {
        if (approver.Id != CreatorUserId)
        {
            IsApproved = true;
        }
    }
}
```

## Complex Workflows

Complex workflows like "every change" can do this instead of `_Temp` tables:

```
public abstract class ChangeBase : Entity<long>, IExtendableObject
{
    public string EntityTypeAssemblyQualifiedName { get; set; }

    public string EntityIdJsonString { get; set; }

    public long ProposerUserId { get; set; }

    public long? ApproverUserId { get; set; }

    public string ExtensionData { get; set; }
}

public class Change : ChangeBase
{
    [NotMapped]
    public Type EntityType => Type.GetType(EntityTypeAssemblyQualifiedName);

    [NotMapped]
    public object EntityId => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(EntityIdJsonString, EntityHelper.GetPrimaryKeyType(EntityType));

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsApproved => ApproverUserId.HasValue && ApproverUserId != ProposerUserId;

    [NotMapped]
    public IDictionary<string, string> ChangedPropertyValuePairs => JObject.Parse(ExtensionData).ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    public Change(EntityIdentifier changedEntityIdentifier, long proposerUserId, IDictionary<string, string> changedPropertyValuePairs)
    {
        EntityTypeAssemblyQualifiedName = changedEntityIdentifier.Type.AssemblyQualifiedName;
        EntityIdJsonString = changedEntityIdentifier.Id.ToJsonString();
        ProposerUserId = proposerUserId;
        ExtensionData = JObject.FromObject(changedPropertyValuePairs).ToString(Formatting.None);
    }

    public bool Approve(long approverUserId)
    {
        if (approverUserId != ProposerUserId)
        {
            ApproverUserId = approverUserId;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class UserAppService // ...
{
    private readonly IRepository<Change, long> _changeRepository;

    public UserAppService(
        IRepository<User, long> repository,
        IRepository<Change, long> changeRepository) // : base(repository)
    {
        _changeRepository = changeRepository;
    }

    public void ChangeUserName(long userId, string newUserName)
    {
        // Validation, etc.

        var changedPropertyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { nameof(User.UserName), newUserName }
        };

        var change = new Change(
            new EntityIdentifier(typeof(User), userId),
            AbpSession.GetUserId(),
            changedPropertyValuePairs
            );

        _changeRepository.Insert(change);
    }

    public void ApproveChange(long changeId)
    {
        // Validation, etc.

        var change = _changeRepository.Get(changeId);

        if (change.EntityType == typeof(User) && change.Approve(AbpSession.GetUserId()))
        {
            var user = Repository.Get((long)change.EntityId);
            var changedPropertyValuePairs = change.ChangedPropertyValuePairs;

            foreach (var changedProperty in changedPropertyValuePairs.Keys)
            {
                switch (changedProperty)
                {
                    case nameof(User.UserName):
                        user.UserName = changedPropertyValuePairs[changedProperty];
                        break;
                    // ...
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome solution, bro. Thanks you again!

Answer (score 3):

**For development**

1. Separate staging and production environments. Develop on one box, test it, get it reviewed and then deploy to a production box. Simple, effective and language agnostic advice.

Since ASP.NET Boilerplate framework included Entity Framework. You could also leverage migrations.

2. After you do your development work, and requires you to "update-database", then your SOP should be to have the admin review the (relatively simple) migrations that will be committed.

I hope that helps.

**For application flow**

There are probably quite a few ways to actually implement this so I'll cover a simple one get your idea's flowing, but keep in mind: The way you need to implement two person integrity must fit how your operating procedures should work, and not the other way around.  Development doesn't drive business operations, business use-cases drive development.

1. Extending existing `Identity*` classes.  Example: The `ApplicationUser` class (it may be named differently, but it derives from `IdentityUser`

   - Create 2 flags (boolean fields) that must be, and can only be turned 'on' by an administrator
   - a single administrator can only turn on 1 flag. (Which means you also have to store which administrator turned on which flag.)
   - The flags can be stored in the existing `Abp*` tables, or you can create a new table
   - Add logic so that the user is not allowed to log in unless those 2 flags are both on.
   - Example: `default IdentityUserRole` has identified and registered, but can not log in. Once both admin's switch the flags on, elevate the users `IdentityUserRole` to a role that is allowed to log in.

Comment: Thanks Adam, but what I mean is a workflow in the application, not in a developing process. I will update my question to make it more clearly.

Comment: Thank you Adam. It is the simple solution but helpful.